# outlook 2010 save sent mail to shared folder

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, shared-folders

In our company some users (Windows 7, Exchange 2003) need to save there sent mails in different, often shared(!) folders. This worked great with the following VBA script in Outlook 2007. They sent their mails and got a popup where they could choose a folder:

---

```
Public Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)

If Item.Class = olMail Then
    Dim myFolder As MAPIFolder
    Dim myOlApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim myOlExp As Outlook.Explorer

    Set myOlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set olNS = myOlApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set myFolder = olNS.PickFolder
    If Not (myFolder Is Nothing) Then
        Set Item.SaveSentMessageFolder = myFolder
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

---

Since they use Outlook 2010 (still Windows 7, exchange 2003) this script is just working as the choose a local/personal folder. As soon as they choose a shared folder the sent mail is just saved under the local/personal "Sent items".

Additionally, it makes me wonder that the outlook-function "save sent element under" (when you write a mail) does also NOT work when you try to save in a shared folder.

The user-permissions on exchange 2003 are still the same, just outlook 2007 was upgraded to 2010.

Any ideas?

Comment: Issues specific to corporate IT support and networks are [off topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic) here. Contact your IT department for assistance.